# Background Image 404 error - File path is correct

Tags: css, sass

I'm hoping someone can help me! I have a background image but when I've pushed it to GitHub it comes up with a 404 error.  I've checked the console and it's loading in the type text/html.  All my other images are loading and the file path for the background is correct.  Is there something else I need to do? Thank you!

```
  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba($Dust_Blue, 0.5),
      rgba($Dust_Blue, 0.2)
    ),
    
    url('/assest/images/background.jpg') center top;
  background-size: cover;
```

[Link to site](https://elliej87.github.io/Portfolio-Site/index.html)
[Image of error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEnWx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by changing the image path

from:
`"assest/images/`
to
`"../../images/`

and by the way, there is a typo there, it should be `assets`

Comment: Great thank you for this! I also had to clear my cache as well as it wasn't initially finding the image! (thanks for the heads up on the spelling! :) ) Do you know why the ../.. has to be used instead of naming the folder name?

Comment: you're welcome! because the path has to be relative to the source (stylesheet) so you're going 2 folders back to find the images folder.

read more here https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#url:~:text=Partial%20URLs%20are%20interpreted%20relative%20to%20the%20source%20of%20the%20style%20sheet%2C%20not%20relative%20to%20the%20document%3A
Since this solved your issue, please mark the answer as the right one :)